# Could I fetch an Enumerable<MimeMessage> from an Enumerable<UniqueId> in Mailkit?

Tags: c#, .net, imap, mailkit

I'm trying to optimize the methods and ways I use to perform a search and retrieving the results.

Actually, I have one method which (for example) searches by body on mails. It uses a TextSearchQuery and so on and I retrieve the List of UniqueIds. I'm interested on working with MimeMessages which basically has everything I need to work with.

```
public IEnumerable<MimeMessage> BuscarEnCuerpoEmail(string texto, bool noLeidos = false, bool flagged = false)
{
    List<MimeMessage> resultado = new List<MimeMessage>();
    try
    {
        imap.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(texto) 
            && !noleidos && !flagged)   //Busca en todos los correos
        {
           var parametrosBusqueda = new TextSearchQuery(SearchTerm.BodyContains, texto)
                .And(SearchQuery.All);
            var resultadoBusqueda = imap.Inbox.Search(parametrosBusqueda);
            return ObtenerMensajes(resultadoBusqueda);
        } . . . .
```

I have a method which adds the MimeMessage to a collection and a `GetMessage` each time...

```
public IEnumerable<MimeMessage> ObtenerMensajes(IEnumerable<UniqueId> ids)
{
    List<MimeMessage> result = new List<MimeMessage>();
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        var message = imap.Inbox.GetMessage(id);
        result.Add(message);
        //yield return message;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there any way to perform that GetMessage in the server and get a List of MimeMessages directly? Like `GetBatchMimeMessages(List<UniqueId>)` or something could be interesting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MailKit doesn't have any built-in way of downloading a collection of messages at a time. Generally you don't want to do that anyway since messages can be of any size and a collection of them can be massive.

IMAP is designed such that you don't really ever need to download multiple messages in full at a time anyway since the purpose of IMAP is to be a remote storage system for mail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jeff. Initially, my class is intended to be used constantly so the supposed e-mails to be downloaded and processed aren't supposed to be huge, so I guess it's quite good for me. Mailkit FTW!